# Derivation of the formula for partial correlation coefficient of second order

Tags: mathematical-statistics, partial-correlation

I came across this formula in some online resources.

$$r_{12.34} = \frac {r_{12.3} - r_{14.3}r_{24.3}}{ \sqrt {(1- r_{14.3}^2 )(1-r_{24.3}^2 )}}$$

I can use this but I wanted a proof of the formula. Can you prove the formula or please direct me to any link with a proof?

Comment: An example of how to derive formulas like this appears at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132725.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a proof of the general case in Section 2.5.3 (pp. 42-43) of Anderson (1984).  The proof covers about a page and half to obtain the general formula
$$\rho_{ij\cdot q+1,...,p} = \frac
{\rho_{ij\cdot q+2,...,p} - \rho_{i, q+1\cdot q+2,...,p} \rho_{j, q+1\cdot q+2,...,p}}
{
\sqrt{1 - \rho^2_{i,q+1\cdot q+2,...,p}}
\sqrt{1 - \rho^2_{j,q+1\cdot q+2,...,p}}
}.$$

Your formula follows on substitution and on a relabeling of indices if needed.

T.W. Anderson (1984) *An Introduction to Multivariate Statistical Analysis*.  Second Edition.  John Wiley & Sons.